# RoboElectric NoClassDefFoundError: org/conscrypt/OpenSSLProvider

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing a Unit Test with Static use of context (because of text translated values) in Android.
I use Kotlin language and I have an issue when running the test.

I'm running the test under :

- Intelij 2022.3.3
- SDK 33
- Kotlin 1.7.10

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/conscrypt/OpenSSLProvider

    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1943)
    at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.findConstructor(Injector.java:262)
    at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.inject(Injector.java:243)
    at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.lambda$new$0(Injector.java:126)
    at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector$MemoizingProvider.get(Injector.java:498)
    at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.getInstanceInternal(Injector.java:224)
    at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.getInstance(Injector.java:208)
    at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.getInstance(Injector.java:202)
    at org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox.lambda$new$0(AndroidSandbox.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader.loadClass(SandboxClassLoader.java:135)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 15 more
```

My Gradle testImplementation

```
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.9'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.11.0'
```

I see this issue on Github but no solution [Link](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/8165)